# How many times does an id appear in date range [r]

Tags: r, date

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450600/count-number-of-observations-rows-per-group-and-add-result-to-data-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179334/count-of-events-per-datetime-r) for answers, but I have not gotten what I've needed to summarize my dataframe. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533139/count-of-unique-values-in-a-rolling-date-range-for-r) is the closest to what I need.

I want to see the number of times a client has ordered in a particular month, and then how many of the unique ids occurred within the month. The "id" is the unique client id, and "date" is when the transaction occurred.

Here is what the data looks like:

Sample Data:

```
id   date
1    3/12/2016
2    3/14/2016
3    3/11/2016
1    4/19/2016
1    4/21/2016
3    5/21/2016
2    6/7/2016
1    6/8/2016
```

And what I would like the result to be is:

Result:

```
date     percent  
03-2016  100%
04-2016  33%
05-2016  33%
06-2016  66%
```

For reference:

```
length(unique(df$id)) = 3
```

Suggestions on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `by` and create a specific `TimePeriod` column:

```
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date, '%m/%d/%Y')
dat$TimePeriod <- paste(format(dat$date, '%Y'),'-',format(dat$date, '%m'))

unique_id <- length(unique(dat$id))

setNames(stack(
  by(dat, dat$TimePeriod, function(x) length(unique(x$id)) / unique_id)
  ), c('percent', 'date'))

    percent      date
1 1.0000000 2016 - 03
2 0.3333333 2016 - 04
3 0.3333333 2016 - 05
4 0.6666667 2016 - 06
```

#### data

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'id   date
1    3/12/2016
                  2    3/14/2016
                  3    3/11/2016
                  1    4/19/2016
                  1    4/21/2016
                  3    5/21/2016
                  2    6/7/2016
                  1    6/8/2016', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I guess a `data.table` version might be something like this: `as.data.table(mydf)[, date := as.IDate(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")][, list(pct = length(unique(id))/unique_id), .(mon_yr = sprintf("%02d-%s", month(date), year(date)))]`. +1

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 : to round to the nearest month, instead of `sprintf` you could use one of the niceties of data.table: `[...] .(mon_yr = round(date, 'month')) [...]`.

Comment: @Jealie, Good call! Thanks.